# Why does auto_arima function from pmdarima package on python is much slower than auto.arima function available on R?

Tags: python, time-series, rstudio, arima, pyramid-arima

I work on a timeseries project with  lot of timeseries and I want to settle it with an automatic function for arima/sarima model. I did it on R with auto.arima function which is very fast and now I'm on python and the auto_arima function (from the pmdarima package) I deal with is really slow.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you a more canonical Python package for ARIMA, such as `statsmodels`:

http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already looked on this package but I need to automate the process, it means a loop on different orders of the arima model and keep the best model defined according to a criterion (AIC for me). The required time for it is really long too.

Comment: `pmdarima` is a wrapper for `statsmodels`